# Terminal control sequence for character display width?

Tags: terminal, xterm

Correct display of Unicode in a terminal would appear to benefit from the displaying app knowing the number of character cells used to display text.  Functions like wcwidth() are a reasonable start, but there can be a lot of variation, for example what a terminal displays for invalid characters, ambiguous width Asian characters, combining characters out of context, etc.

Would it be reasonable to extend terminal apps with a new control sequence to measure with display width of a string, which display apps could use to characterize the terminal?  If so, what details are worth considering, e.g. what sequence to use, whether to specify UTF-8, also how to handle terminals that do not know this hypothetical new control sequence?   Would it have any likelihood of wide adoption?

If not, what is the flaw in the idea?  Is perhaps reading the cursor position after display a better (and already supported) option?  Or is there a good different approach?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need, because the existing *cursor position report* (which can be used to get the position before and after printing a string) gives the length.

Adding a new control sequence to get the attributes of a character (width, combining, controls such as tab) wouldn't help much because the application still has to work with the system's locale information for **performance reasons**: it would drastically slow down an application if it had to ask after each character where the cursor really was.